# div above div (both bottom: 0px;)

Tags: html, css

I want to align elements inside div

a - > to the top

b - > to the bottom

c - > above b element (but also to the bottom of the div container)

```
#container {    position: relative}
#a {    position: absolute;    top: 0px;}
#b {    position: absolute;    bottom: 0px;}
#C {????}
```

**I didn't find a way for C**

[image: like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put `c` inside `b` and position it absolutely with `bottom: 100%`, thus `c` will always be on top of `b`.

```css
.d {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.a, .b, .c{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 40px;
  left: 0;
}
.a {
  top: 0;
  background: lightgreen;
}
.b {
  bottom: 0;
  background: tomato;
}
.c {
  bottom: 100%;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="d">
  <div class="a">a
  </div>
  <div class="b">b
  <div class="c">c
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="d">
  <div class="a">a
  </div>
  <div class="b"> Block b Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsu
  <div class="c">c
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use another container for below divs.

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="a"></div>
   <div id="container-below">
      <div id="b"></div>
      <div id="c"></div>
   </div>
</div>

#container {    position: relative}
#a {    position: absolute;    top: 0px;}
#container-below {    position: absolute;    bottom: 0px;}
```

Answer (score -1):

please start using flexbox and soon css grids :P

```css
.p > div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red
}

.p {
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: beige;
  width: 200px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.b {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="p">

  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```